# Maven spring boot pre-integration-test timeout error

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

When I run the command `install` of my server's Lifecycle I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.507 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-10T15:32:41+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 69M/596M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:start (pre-integration-test) on project challenger-server-boot: Spring application did not start before the configured timeout (30000ms -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

It obviously comes from the timeout settings but I cannot find where I have to change this value...

Not sure if it can help but here's some of my pom.xml related to the unit and integration testings:

```
    <!-- Unit testing -->
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <!-- Integration testing -->
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Here's the debug log: http://pastebin.com/kUkufHFS

Comment: Can you re-run your maven statement with adding -X for debug logging for more information? thanks
You can paste your full debug logging to some online paste text, paste bin , ex: http://pasted.co/

Comment: Why are you trying to defining naming conventions which are already part of maven-surefire-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin. There is no need to exclude `**/*IT.java` for maven-surefire-plugin or include them on the other hand in maven-failsafe-plugin...

Comment: @LamLe: I added the debug log to the question

Comment: @khmarbaise I did not know that, thanks for the information

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are trying to start a spring boot app before in pre-integration-test phase.
The spring-boot-maven-plugin StartMojo class (org.springframework.boot.maven) is complaining because the app is not started within the default timeout, wich is defined by the attributes "wait" (defautl value: 500 ms) and "maxAttempts" (default: 60) -> 500 * 60.

```
/**
 * The number of milli-seconds to wait between each attempt to check if the spring
 * application is ready.
 */
@Parameter
private long wait = 500;

/**
 * The maximum number of attempts to check if the spring application is ready.
 * Combined with the "wait" argument, this gives a global timeout value (30 sec by
 * default)
 */
@Parameter
private int maxAttempts = 60;
```

"wait" and "maxAttempts" are annotated @Parameter, which means you can change their value from within your pom file, in the plugin configuration like this:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
              <wait>1000</wait>
              <maxAttempts>180</maxAttempts>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
              ...
     </executions> 
</plugin>
```